# Integral of $e^{-xy}$ is a Dirac Delta

Tags: integration, solution-verification, dirac-delta, quantum-field-theory, superalgebra

I was looking at [papers about the SYK model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08482) page 33 (equation 112), in which they write

$$\int\mathscr{D}\Sigma\,\mathscr{D}G~\exp\left\{-\frac{N}{2}\int\limits_{\left[0,\beta\right]^2} d\tau~d\tau^{\prime}~\Sigma(\tau,\tau^{\prime})\left(G(\tau,\tau^{\prime})~-~\sum_{i=1}^N\psi_i(\tau)\psi_i(\tau^{\prime})\right)\right\}~=~1.\tag{112}$$

This would follow from $$\int d\sigma\,dg\ e^{-\sigma g}=1.\tag{*}$$

Wolfram alpha confirms this as a Cauchy principle value.

How would this be proved?

Comment: Similar question on Phys.SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/456749/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP asks about heuristic manipulations of a [functional integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration) in Ref. 1. This question (v5) seems to belong more to [Phys.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) than [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/). Functional integration is a huge topic. In this answer, we will only discuss the underlying ordinary integral.

1. Since the [Grassmann-odd variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) $\psi_i=\psi_i^{\ast}$ are real [supernumbers](https://planetmath.org/supernumber), the [constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)
   $$G(\tau,\tau^{\prime})~-~\sum_{i=1}^N\psi_i(\tau)\psi_i(\tau^{\prime})$$
   is an $\color{red}{\text{imaginary}}$ Grassmann-even supernumber. (Recall that complex conjugation reverses the order of supernumbers.)
2. OP's underlying integral (*) in eq. (112) is therefore$^1$
   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathrm{d}\sigma~ e^{-\sigma g}~=~2\pi \delta(\color{red}{i}g), \qquad \color{red}{i}g~\in~\mathbb{R}. $$

References:

1. G. Sarosi, *AdS2 holography and the SYK model,* [arXiv:1711.08482](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08482).

--

$^1$ Ref. 1 uses a so-called [Euclidean formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation), cf. footnote 36.

Comment: But $\sigma$ is a field. Why is there a factor of $i$ under Wick rotation?

Comment: I updated the answer.